# MacOS tool to count data incoming and outcoming

Tags: macos, mac, networking

I'm looking for a tool for my Mac which allows for counting how many data (in kB) go out and in. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Activity Monitor (in your Utilities folder under Applications) will do that for you, you don't need any additional tools.

Answer (score 0):

Activity Monitor is good, but if you want another option, consider [MenuMeters.](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/)